# How do I use message stack (or other) to send new blog post (nodes) to "email-only subscribers" like Wordpress?

Tags: notifications

How can we set up Drupal 7 to let someone simply put in their email and then receive an email notification every time a blog (node) is created?

In my ecosystem I already have rules, views, CiviCRM, and the message-stack/flag, but do not see a clear and easy way to do this without forcing the user to register an account, flag the content, and receive a rules-based email that way.

To summmarize: We want an anonymous user to put in only their email, and then receive an email every time a blog node is posted, automatically.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: You just need anything that allows users to input their data, then use rules to create a user or add the email to a list, and then loop that when you create content.. Can you give more details about what modules you have installed?

Comment: I don't want users to be created necessarily. Is that a requirement?  I can use any modules.

Comment: It's not a requirement. You just a form that can be submitted anonymously, like an entityform (or a custom one), and a place to store the emails that Rules can access.. I'm not familiar with CiviCRM. Does it have entityform / field collection? You could even just have nodes for each submission. There are many ways to do it so I'm hesitant to recommend installing modules.

Comment: CiviCRM does have data fields/profiles that can collect data, and they can be exposed as Entities. I am going to use the answer below as I am looking for a holistic solution that has been thought through. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three modules that support this type of subscription and notification workflow without requiring subscribers to actually be registered users on the Drupal site:

1. Simple Subscription https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_subscription
2. Total Subscription https://www.drupal.org/project/total_subscription
3. Simple News https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews

Below are some notes and caveats to each module/approach:

- ***Simple Subscription***: the 7.x-1.x branch provides the basics, but hasn't seen much maintenance/activity since the move toward the 7.x-2.x alpha in 2016.  The alpha has some nice features and intent, but is also just an alpha release.  This module has token support and can work nicely with out of the box rules based messaging.
- ***Total Subscription***: This module does not offer to site managers any administrative functionality to unsubscribe email addresses or toggle on/off notifications for testing purposes. You'd have to enable/disable the module to toggle notifications (all or nothing) for any content types or taxonomies setup to publish subscription notifications.  Custom html email templates can be generated with the HTML Mail module, but templating only supports the default body/summary field and not any custom fields applied to the content type.  Messages are queued and sent via Drupalcron.
- ***SimpleNews***: This module is probably the most stable of the options and offers a D8 version; but it requires the extra step for content managers having to switch to the Newsletter tab and manually send the notifications after node creation.